# How to retrieve the name 'Group' using component query, by default active is true for this : ExtJS

Tags: extjs, jasmine, component-query

Below is the snippet of the code in which we have four tabs. The Group tab is set as default. So when the view is loaded, the Group is enabled by default.

```
xtype: 'oneclient-toggles-btn',
                itemId: 'productToggle',
                height: 40,
                margin: '17 25 0 0',
                btnList: [{
                    name: 'Group',
                    refer : "Group",
                    active: true
                }, {
                    name: '&nbsp;&nbsp;All&nbsp;&nbsp;',
                    refer : "All",
                    active: false
                }, {
                    name: 'My Favourites',
                    refer : "Favourite",
                    active: false
                }, {
                    name: 'Invalid Data',
                    refer : "Invalid",
                    active: false
                }, {
                    name: 'Inactive',
                    refer : "Inactive",
                    active: false
                }
```

I need to test using Jasmine, if the default tab is 'Group'. How do I do it? Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: `oneclient-toggles-btn` is not a built in framework class.

Comment: yes it is not. it is user defined. how do I render the view in jasmine and do the above?

Comment: How am I supposed to answer that? It's like me asking "I wrote a class `Foo`, how do I use it?" What would you ask me?